# Что делать с рекомендациями, которые потенциально могут решить проблему?

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Некий [Дмитрий Гвоздь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10387/%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%93%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%8C) написал, что "[В опубликованном сообщении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/444193) не содержится решения вопроса". Действительно ли это так?

Comment: _sidenote_: это автоматический комментарий из очереди проверок. когда выбираешь определенное действие

Comment: @Grundy Да это понятно. Я знаю, что такие комментарии генерируются при отправлении соответствующей тревоги. Нормальность данной тревоги я и пытаюсь выяснить

Answer (score 3):

Сложный вопрос, на самом деле. Некоторые считают, что подобные ответы с догадками должны быть в комментариях, а в ответе нужно писать уже работающее решение.

Конкретно в данном случае, возможно, Дмитрий исходил из того, что автор вопроса так путь и указал, посему этот ответ в целом довольно бессмысленный был бы для автора вопроса, т.к. он и так считает, скорей всего, что путь правильный указал.

Именно поэтому есть очередь проверок, где решение выносится коллегиально.

Comment: Хорошо, пусть это будет написано не как догадка. Тогда это будет просто неправильный ответ. А их мы не удаляем. То есть, если у тебя есть догадка и ты ее хочешь высказать так, чтобы ее не удалили, нужно просто не указывать, что это догадка(хоть это и повысит вероятность получения минуса). Бюрократизм, не считаете?

Comment: Думаю, что ответы-догадки приемлемы в тех случаях, когда невозможно получить более точную информацию путем уточняющего комментария. Например, ответ вида "Возможно, у вас по N-ому пути нет картинки" будет неприемлем, так как можно задать уточняющий вопрос "А у вас точно по N-ому пути есть картинка?".

Comment: @Miron да, неправильные ответы мы не удаляем и не переносим в комментарии.

Comment: @Miron при недостатке информации лучше сначала уточнить в комментарии под вопросом вместо написания ответа.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, даже предложение в ответе неверное - путь должен быть на сайте, а не на компьютере. Я его несколько раз перечитал, чтобы угадать, что же может быть быть в этом ответе правдоподобного. Во-вторых, автору вопроса хорошо бы уточнить, в чём именно заключается "не работает". У меня "не работает" абсолютно не ассоциируется с 404, на который рассчитан ответ. Впрочем, другая причина, которая может быть, не соответствует коду в вопросе.

Comment: А разве нужно удалять неверные ответы?

Comment: @Miron, ну в принципе обычно нет :)